Large JSON encode
I was performing a JSON file encoding in my project and noticed that the method for encoding is synchronous. While discussing this with a friend, he questioned whether a very large JSON file could cause some lag/delay due to this synchronous method. Is there any type of JSON encoding that is not synchronous for such cases?

Are you asking if there already exists a pre-made solution for async json, or are you asking if you can program your own solution?

@JohnGordon Hello, I'm asking if there is already a way to solve this

I think you should use Isolate for large Json encode/decode.

https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/background-parsing
